# Creating Boolean raster layer / QGIS PCRaster View error: type is ordinal, legal type is boolean

Tags: qgis, raster, viewshed, boolean, pcraster

In QGIS 3.30, I try to use [PCRaster `View`](https://pcraster.geo.uu.nl/pcraster/4.4.0/documentation/pcraster_manual/sphinx/op_view.html) tool. I have two rasters, saved in PCRster (`.map`) format as PCRaster plugin seems to only accept this filetype. Both rasters have the same extent, resolution, CRS and contain no `NODATA` values:

1. Layer `DEM`, Data type: `Float32`, values from `-100` (former nodata values, filled with [Fill NoData cells](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#fill-nodata-cells)) to 2549.242188
2. Layer `binary_raster`, Data type: Int32, containing just values `0` and `1`

When I run the tool, I get an error message, see below. I don't understand what's going wrong. I suspect that somehow I should have a "boolean raster layer" (error message mentions `type is ordinal, legal type is boolean`). The [documentation mentions](https://pcraster.geo.uu.nl/pcraster/4.4.0/documentation/pcraster_manual/sphinx/op_view.html) for 2nd input layer "viewpoints: spatial boolean", without providing further information. So I'm not sure about that and how to do it. I thought having a layer with just 0/1 should be OK.

What should I do to run the tool correctly?

[image]

**Here is the error message I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pcraster\operations.py", line 3040, in view
_pcraster._rte().checkAndExec(operator, 2)
RuntimeError: argument nr. 2 of function 'view': type is ordinal, legal type is boolean

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/DU/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\english/python/plugins\pcraster_tools\processing\algorithms\pcraster_view_algorithm.py", line 98, in processAlgorithm
Viewshed = view(DEM, Points)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pcraster\operations.py", line 3044, in view
raise RuntimeError("view: %s" % (str(exception)))
RuntimeError: view: argument nr. 2 of function 'view': type is ordinal, legal type is boolean
```